# area of a triangle using double integral

Tags: integration

I can find the area of a triangle with known vertices but the problem here is that the question is general: I have to use double integral to prove that the area of the triangle is:

$$A_{\text{triangle}}=\frac {\text{base}\times\text{height}}{2}$$

I assume that the width is $b$ and the height is $h$ so I have to integrate from $0$ to $b$ and from $0$ to $h$ but this would lead me to the area of a rectangle, that is, $bh$.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Integrate from $0$ to $b$, but don't integrate from $0$ to $h$.

Answer (score 1):

You can place one vertex at the origin, and another at $(b,0)$.  The other vertex we assume is at $(t,h)$, where $t \in (0,b)$.  The area of the triangle is then

$$\int_0^t dx \, \int_0^{h x/t} dy  + \int_t^b dx \, \int_h^{h (b-x)/(b-t)} dy$$

which is

$$\begin{align}\frac{h}{t} \frac12 t^2 + h \int_t^b dx \frac{b-x}{b-t} &= \frac12 h t + \frac{h}{b-t}[b (b-t) -\frac12 (b^2-t^2)]\\ &= \frac12 h t + b h -\frac12 h(b+t)\\ &= \frac12 b h\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach. Just assume it has the three vertices $(0,0),(0,b)$ and $(c,h)$ such that $b,c >0$. Now, you need to

1) find the equation of the line passing through points $(0,0),(c,h)$

2) find the line passing through the points $(0,b), (c,h) $

3) consider a horizontal strip; i.e. the double integral

$$ \iint_{D} dxdy .$$